# Inline-block element mouseenter/mouseleave issue with firefox

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have a pretty simple navigation element that I've made.

It looks fine in Chrome and Safari, but when I went to view it in Firefox I noticed that the hidden piece of the navigation "jumps" up when you roll over "About". I am using a CSS reset.

**The HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>
            <a>About</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a>People</a></li>
                <li><a>Approach</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>Projects</a></li>
        <li><a>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

​
**The CSS:**

```
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.sub-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}​
```

**The JS:**

```
$('.sub-menu').hide();

$('nav > ul > li').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).find('ul.sub-menu').stop().animate({width: 'toggle'});
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $(this).find('ul.sub-menu').stop().animate({width: 'toggle'});
    }
});
```

**The Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/HYPX8/

**The Screenshot:**

[image]

I have tried using just `inline` and the same thing occurs.

I tried using `float: left` on all of the li elements as well as `.sub-menu` but then I run in to an issue with the children `li` elements of `.sub-menu` collapsing on `mouseleave`

Can anyone recommend how to fix this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 0**

If you comment out `$('.sub-menu').hide();` and toggle the width you see that the issues lies with how JQuery is changing the CSS because it renders out correctly on load.  I'd investigate that further.

Also, changing width to height produces something that you might want to use. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/HYPX8/5/.

```
$(this).find('.sub-menu').stop().animate({height: 'toggle'});
```

---

**Solution Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/HYPX8/2/.

Adding the following to the `.sub-menu` CSS seems to prevent that drop from occurring.

```
height: 10px;
margin-right: 16px;
```

It looks like if you really wanted to you could combine the CSS but it adds a little padding to the left.

```
nav li, .sub-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

But, to get the desired result, all you need is the following.

```
.sub-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: It's still doing it on http://jsfiddle.net/HYPX8/2/, if I reduce height to 8px on .sub-menu it works on FF but then breaks on Chrome (http://jsfiddle.net/HYPX8/3/)

Comment: Weird. Doesn't do that for my version of FF. What about `height:inherit;` for `.sub-menu`.

Comment: `display: inline-table;` works for me (http://jsfiddle.net/HYPX8/4/) but ruins the animation.

Comment: In the end, I think you're going to have cross browser issues. IE9 requires `height: 9px;'.